# navigation bar not showing with a programmatically made UINavigationController

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller named navController made programmatically in my modal view controller during its viewDidLoad:

```
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
self.navController.view=self.view;
[self setView:self.navController.view];
```

But when i launch the modal view controller i dont see the navigation bar, just the standard view i made in IB. Whats wrong?

Comment: This is code pretty confused. You can't set the view from one controller to the view from another controller. And controllers don't generally expect their views to be added as subviews of other controllers views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution cannot work.

Suppose that you have your modal controller called `ModalViewController`. It's a simple `UIViewController` linked with a xib created interface.

Now, at some point you need to present `ModalViewController` modally. As you wrote in your specification, I think you want to use also a `UINavigationController` and control its navigation bar.

The code to do this could be the following, where `presentModally` could be a method that it's not contained in `ModalViewController`.

```
- (void)presentModally:(id)sender {

   ModalViewController *modalController = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalView" bundle:nil]; 

   // Create the navigation controller and present it.
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:modalController];

   [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
}
```

Now, within `viewDidLoad` of your `ModalViewController` you have access to navigationController property. In this manner you can control `navigationController` behaviour. For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // the code changes the title for the navigation bar associated with the UINavigationController
    self.title = @"Set from ModalViewController";
}
```

**Some notes**

To understand how `UINavigationController` works read [UINavigationController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

To understand how modal controllers work read [Modal view controllers documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

The code I provided is a simple example and only demonstrative (I've written by hand so check for syntax). You need to make attention to memory management and how to present modal controllers. In particular, as Apple documentation suggests, to present modal controllers you need to follow these steps:

1. Create the view controller you want to present.
2. Set the modalTransitionStyle property of the view controller to the desired value.
3. Assign a delegate object to the view controller. Typically the delegate is the presenting view controller. The delegate is used by the presented view controllers to notify the presenting view controller when it is ready to be dismissed. It may also communicate other information back to the delegate.
4. Call the presentViewController:animated:completion: method of the current view controller, passing in the view controller you want to present.
5. Trigger (when necessary) some action to dismiss the modal controller.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @flexaddicted could you explain the method in a swift version ? Tks